# Map routes into other routes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm having some troubles with `routes` in Ruby on Rails v5.2.0

Currently, I have a **resource** called `users`, so that I have a controller which takes actions (for example `index`) whenever I start my server in localhost on port 3000 and type in my browser 
`localhost:3000/users/`

Is there an easy way to map the requests for this resource to the app root?
Basically, I'm trying to achieve this:
`localhost:3000/users/` --> `localhost:3000/`

`localhost:3000/users/new/` --> `localhost:3000/new/`

This is how my `routes.rb` file looks like right now:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :users
    get 'landing/index'
    get 'welcome/index'

    resources :users

    root to: 'landing#index'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following lines to your `routes.rb` file

Change

```
root to: 'landing#index'
```

to

```
root "users#index"`
```

and add the line

```
get "/new" => "users#new"
```

Also if you want to learn more on routing, here is the link
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR -** Rails doesn't have a `root` model generator for routing

You can manually create the individuals routes

```
get :new, to: "users#new", as: "new_user"
...
```

However while using the rails generators `resources` you are just specifying a shorthand for

```
scope :model do
    get :new, to: "model#new", as: "new_model"
    ...
end
```

You can checkout the rails guide to routing for more specifics on explicit creation
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

**HACKY SOLUTION**

```
root to: "users#index", as: "users"
get :new, to: "users#new", as: "new_user"
post "/", to: "users#create"
scope ":id" do
    root to: "users#show"
    get :edit, to: "users#edit", as: "edit_user"
    patch "/", to: "users#update"
    ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks that what you want is to 'mute' `users` from the url. An option for this is to call `path: ''` on `users` like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  get 'landing/index'
  get 'welcome/index'

  resources :users, path: '' # <-- HERE

  root to: 'landing#index'
end
```

> **The value you give to `path:` is going to replace the resource name.**
>   
>   In this scenario `users` is being replaced with an empty string `''`, but it could be any other string.

This will remove `users`. However, you must consider that `root to: 'landing#index` AND `users#index` are both pointing to `localhost:3000/`

Without knowing your app, an option to solve this scenario, could be to have  `landing#index` as root for gustes (not authenticated users) and `users#index` as a root for authenticated users.